# react-native expo issue: check method of `SceneView`

Tags: react-native, expo

I don't understand why my code doesn't run the orther devices wheras my code is checked ok in my old device. This is notification:

> ```
> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `SceneView`.
> ```

```
This error is located at:
    in SceneView (created by StackViewLayout)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent (created by Card)
    in Card (created by Container)
    in Container (created by StackViewLayout)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by StackViewLayout)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by StackViewLayout)
    in StackViewLayout (created by withOrientation)
    in withOrientation (created by Transitioner)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Transitioner)
    in Transitioner (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by KeyboardAwareNavigator)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRootComponent)
    in RootErrorBoundary (created by ExpoRootComponent)
    in ExpoRootComponent
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRootComponent)
    in RootErrorBoundary (created by ExpoRootComponent)
    in ExpoRootComponent
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

In my code app.js. The method Screens and View was ok. So what must i do?

Comment: Did you found the solution ?

Comment: Can yo post the code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i your problem but i got a similar error when i import a module in the wrong way, below is wrong:

> import {myDefault} from '/modules/my-module.js';

now is correct:

> import myDefault from '/modules/my-module.js';